# Deduce that the intersection of two distinct planes through origin is straight line thorough origin

Tags: linear-algebra

I know how to prove that intersection of two distinct planes is a line (inclusion - exclusion principle)
Given a vector space $V$ and two subspaces $W_1$,$W_2$, you get that $\dim(W_1+W_2)=\dim W_1+\dim W_2−\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$
where $W_1+W_2=\mathrm{span}({W_1 \cup W_2})$ is the minimal subspace which contains both $W_1$ and $W_2$.

$$\dim(W_1+W_2)=3.$$

$3=2+2-\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) \implies$ it is a line.
What I can't think of is how I show that this line is passing through the origin. With help of equations of plane and basis of subspace containing this line. Both normal and converse way.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to format your posts.

Comment: I think you're probably overthinking it! If the point at the origin is in both of the planes, then it is in the intersection, by definition of "intersection". Since you've shown the intersection is a line, we now know the intersection is a line containing the point at the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is referred to $\mathbb{R}^3$. In this case, $W_1$ and $W_2$ are different planes. $\dim(W_1) + \dim(W_2) = 2 + 2 = 4 \Rightarrow \dim(W_1 \cap W_2) \leq 1$. Since those planes are different, their intersection is the origin, and one can conclude that their intersection has dimension $1$, which means that it is a line.

And why does this line pass through the origin? Well, I don't know if you have saw the fact that the intersection between two vectorial spaces is a vectorial space, and therefore it has to pass through origin. Every vectorial space contains "the origin".